# Hough Gradient Method misses some circles

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection, omr

Consider the images below:

[image]

[image]

As can be seen, many circles are not detected. I have already played with

`param1` and `param2` (`cv2.HoughCircles`)

in the code below:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Load the image and downscale it
img = Image.open('/tmp/F01-02.jpg')
img = img.resize((img.size[0] // 2, img.size[1] // 2))  # downscale by a factor of 2
open_cv_image = np.array(img) 

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(open_cv_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# Apply Hough transform
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 40, param1=5, param2=30, minRadius=7, maxRadius=10)

# Ensure at least some circles were found
if circles is not None:
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        cv2.circle(open_cv_image, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 2)

pil_image = Image.fromarray(open_cv_image)
pil_image.save('/tmp/result.jpg')
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: hough is a bad idea. don't use that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @ChristophRackwitz. What would you advise instead Hough?

Comment: this is OMR. forms have specific appearance to make this easy. forms come with a barcode that encodes the type (and maybe identity) of the form. forms also contain easily locatable fiducials. all the rest of the form content is then located relative to those fiducials (and form type, assuming you have multiple form types). there *never* is any "finding of circles" or boxes. you already know, from having designed the form, where the form elements are, relative to the fiducials. you'd just sample an area in/around the circle and perform some simple statistics.

Comment: no, "fiducials" does not mean augmented reality. it means simple circles or squares.

Comment: Thanks again, @ChristophRackwitz. True, that is the conventional way of approaching the problem. Since I have a curious mind, I am trying to approach the problem without fiducials at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### HoughCircles

I managed to find every circle of interest by avoiding the downscale step at **line 7** and using the following arguments for the **HoughCircles** function

```
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image=gray, method=cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1.7, minDist=10, param1=100, param2=30, minRadius=2, maxRadius=15)
```

result:

[image]

I don't know how robust this approach is, it would be necessary to test with a wider range of inputs. Maybe other methods not using **HoughCircles** might be more robust (*e.g.* detecting the grid itself and inferring the circle position).

#### Template matching

This appears to be more robust, it uses template matching with a template I produced by hand, i would recommend something like this over the **HoughCircles**. It seems to work fine even with the downscaling:

Template:

[image]

Warning: I filled it with gray as a dirty way to compensate for it being filled or not (kind of detect both).It is a better idea to create a template for each case for using the opencv template matching, something like this:

[image][image]

You can adjust the sensitivity with the variable threshold:

```
threshold = 0.7
```

Example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Load the image and downscale it
img = Image.open('input.png')
img = img.resize((img.size[0] // 2, img.size[1] // 2))  # downscale by a factor of 2
open_cv_image = np.array(img) 

template = Image.open('template.png')
template = template.resize((template.size[0] // 2, template.size[1] // 2))  # downscale by a factor of 2
open_cv_template = np.array(template)

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(open_cv_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
grayTemplate = cv2.cvtColor(open_cv_template, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

w, h = grayTemplate.shape[::-1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(gray,grayTemplate,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.7
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.circle(open_cv_image, (int(pt[0] + w/2), int(pt[1] + h/2)), 5, (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("image", res)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imshow("image", open_cv_image)

cv2.waitKey(0)

pil_image = Image.fromarray(open_cv_image)
pil_image.save('/tmp/result.jpg')
```

Template matching result:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Detecting holes would also be a great approach, see: OpenCV detecting drilled holes. Remember, you should first detect the grid, then apply your procedure. Sometimes, the labels outside the grid could be detected as circles as well, which would be unwanted

Comment: Thanks, @DeltadeDirac! Indeed, with your approach, I can detect all circles, but, unfortunately, more circles outside the grid. I will research for ways to detect the grid.

Comment: you don't have a solution for assigning an identity (or coordinates) to any of those form elements. that would be required to evaluate the form. -- I would not recommend this approach at all. the usual OMR approach doesn't "look for" form elements at all. it determines form type and finds fiducials, which are designed to be easily located. fiducials establish a coordinate system on the scanned form. relative to *that*, form field content is evaluated.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I agree. A solution including fiducials would be even better, if it is allowed to introduce the element.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @DeltadeDirac: the template approach idea appears to be a lot more robust. Unfortunately, after having played with the `threshold`, the best I got was: [preview](https://i.imgur.com/lLLoMck.png). Maybe your original template was transparent inside the circle?

Comment: You must downscale the template only if you downscale the input. Try with threshold = 0.7 and no downscaling

Comment: I have just used a template that is a screen-shot of a circle of the original image -- and your code works perfectly! Great idea! If I use a template with a filled circle, it detects all filled circles and no empty circle, which is perfect for my goal. Thanks a lot, @DeltadeDirac!

Comment: I filled it with gray as a dirty way to compensate for it being filled or not (detect both). If you are looking for the filled ones/empty ones independently it would be ideal to have a template for each. You are welcome.